# How to include xml path into hash using perl

Tags: xml, perl

I have some xml files in a directory , so I am searching required xml files in that directory and storing xml data in a hash data structure using  below script. But my problem is I need to save the file path of each xml file in the hash But Can any one help me how to save file path in hash data 
I written script like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Simple;
use Carp;
 use File::Find;
use File::Spec::Functions qw( canonpath );  
use Data::Dumper;

my @ARGV ="C:/Main/work"; die "Need directories\n" unless @ARGV;
 find(
 sub {
    return unless ( /(_service\.xml)$/ and -f );
    Hash_information();
    return;
},
@ARGV
);

sub Hash_information {
my $path= $_;

my $xml = new XML::Simple;
my $data = $xml->XMLin("$path", ForceArray => [  
'Service','SystemReaction','SW','HW','Component' , 'BM'],
                             KeyAttr=>{Service=>'Id'}  );
   print Dumper ($data);
 return;
  }
```

using above script I am getting all service xml files form folder and using XML::Simple storing in a hash data structure. Now I want to save file path of each xml file in the hash data structure. Can any one help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: ps. you can leave off a naked `return` at the end of a `sub` … but don't you mean to return the `$data` or store it somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the subroutine for File::Find, $File::Find::name is the complete path name.  Pass that to your Hash_information subroutine.

```
...
find(
    sub {
        return unless ( /(_service\.xml)$/ and -f );
        Hash_information($File::Find::name);
...
sub Hash_information {
my ($path) = @_;
...
```

Comment: Sorry for asking because I am new to perl , How to pass $File::Find::name to $data. or hash_information subroutine. I am struggling with this from last two days.You mean just assign to $data.

Comment: I have added the guts of what I suggested.